# React Native's createStackNavigator()

Tags: react-native

I try to write some react native code to navigate between screens.

Follow the site https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating, I couldn't find much information on the function `createStackNavigator()` that creates a stack: `const Stack = createStackNavigator();`

Is there any complete React Native Navigation documentation somewhere that explains in details the const Stack instance's attributes beside `Stack.Navigator`, `Stack.Screen`? What else can we do with the `Stack` instance? Just like a Java object created from a class, it has methods and attributes and you can find plenty of Java doc for it. Where can I find good doc for React Native's `createStackNavigator()`?

Comment: There is a whole section for it! Just scroll a bit lower :)
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [react-navigation-stack-github](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/stack/src/index.tsx), you can see that the way Stack is expanded, you have `<Stack.Navigator>` and `<Stack.Screen>` - however within those jsx templates, you can interface with the following:

```
// Animation settings
CardStyleInterpolators,
HeaderStyleInterpolators,
TransitionSpecs,
TransitionPresets,

//Components
StackView,
Header,
HeaderTitle, 
HeaderBackButton, 
HeaderBackground,

// Context
CardAnimationContext,
HeaderHeightContext, 
GestureHandlerRefContext,

// hooks
useCardAnimation,
useHeaderHeight,
useGestureHandlerRef,

// types
StackNavigationOptions,
StackNavigationProp,
StackScreenProps,
StackHeaderProps,
StackHeaderLeftButtonProps,
StackHeaderTitleProps,
StackCardInterpolatedStyle,
StackCardInterpolationProps,
StackCardStyleInterpolator,
StackHeaderInterpolatedStyle,
StackHeaderInterpolationProps,
StackHeaderStyleInterpolator,
```

As mentioned by [Taras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8838317/taras-danyliuk), the docs have more detailed explanations on those interfaces.

**[Example in docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headerbackground)**

```
import { BlurView } from 'expo-blur';

// ...

<Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeScreen}
  options={{
    headerTransparent: true,
    headerBackground: () => (
      <BlurView tint="light" intensity={100} style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill} />
    ),
  }}
/>;
```

We can see that in the `index.tsx`, that `headerBackground` has been defined as an export, which has been exposed as an option in `props.options`

Comment: Super!! Thanks Taras and Denis. This give me a good chunk of React Native navigation info to dig in for the weekend.